# Error al encadenar strings : no operator "<<" matches these operands

Tags: c++, operador, string

mi problema es muy simple. No se por que no me deja encadenar strings en C++.
He puesto lo siguiente y me da error en el operador '<<'. El error es 'no operator "<<" matches these operands.
El codigo es este:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string a = "ABC";
    std::string b = "DFG";
    a += b;
    std::cout << a;

    return 0;
}
```

También he intentado lo siguiente y me da error en "DFG". El error es 'expression must have integral or enum type'.
El código es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string a = "ABC" + "DFG";

    return 0;
}
```

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 2):

En el primer ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string a = "ABC";
    std::string b = "DFG";
    a += b;
    std::cout << a;

    return 0;
}
```

El código es correcto y debería funcionar, como puedes comprobar <kbd>[aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bZcSACFtYPn8f8kF)</kbd>. En caso de aparecer algún problema puede ser que te falte la cabecera:

```
#include <string>
```

Ya que es posible que `iostream` no la incluya.

En el segundo caso:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string a = "ABC" + "DFG";

    return 0;
}
```

Estás intentando sumar **dos punteros a char**, y, por defecto, no existe una sobrecarga para dicho operador que haga lo que pretendes.

Ten en cuenta que tanto `"ABC"` como `"DFG"` son de tipo `char const*` y no de tipo `std::string`. El código equivalente a tu ejemplo sería el siguiente:

```
char const* cad = "ABC" + "DFG";
std::string a = cad;
```

Aquí se ve más claro el motivo por el que tu ejemplo no funciona.

La alternativa puede ser convertir de forma explícita una de las dos cadenas a tipo `std::string`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string a = std::string("ABC") + "DFG";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*La alternativa puede ser convertir de forma explícita una de las dos cadenas a tipo `std::string`*" o usar el UDL de cadena: `auto a = "ABC"s + "DFG";` (que viene a ser lo mismo).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Es otra forma de expresarlo :)